# Blazor HTTPS call with bearer token fails strangely

Tags: https, blazor, bearer-token

I have this POC in Blazor 3.1 and I make at Get call with Bearer in the header. This used to go quite well but now I get an error almost everytime I try (I get TypeError in the browser console).

Now comes the interesing part. If I execute  chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\blazor-chrome-debug" https://localhost:5001/ everything works!!!

I thought that this was probably some kind of an async problem but I cannot see any problems.

Can anyone comment on what the diffence with using normal dotnet run and the above mentioned command is?

Kind regards 
Martin

Comment: Did you try to clear you cookies ?

Comment: I did try to clear the cookies but that did not work. However I've found a hack that almost makes it a no problem. Just run the chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 after you've runned in VS. But why did you suspect the cookies agua from mars?

Comment: It's a common issue when debugging with oauth. You can be authentified with a cookie instead of the jwt token.